# RabbitMQ on Vagrant: Can telnet to port 5672, but cannot connect to Rabbit

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, vagrant, easynetq

I have RabbitMQ running on a Vagrant box (using VirtualBox). I have assigned an IP on a public network.

Now, from another machine, I wish to connect via AMQP, using EasyNetQ. When trying that, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to connect to Broker: '172.16.130.20', Port: 5672 VHost: '/'. ExceptionMessage: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'
```

Now, if I try to telnet to that IP on port 5672 (from the same machine where I run the .NET code), I get connected fine.

What could be the reason for EasyNetQ not being able to connect ?

Comment: Looks like it was already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882318/easynetq-fails-to-publish-to-rabbitmq-persistentchannel-timed-out

Comment: That's it ! The error message had sent me in the wrong direction looking for network issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user with valid credentials must be specified in the connectionstring when not using localhost. An authentication error will result in the error message above. See previous question: [EasyNetQ fails to publish to RabbitMQ - PersistentChannel timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882318/easynetq-fails-to-publish-to-rabbitmq-persistentchannel-timed-out)

---

Also, you need to allow remote connections from the guest user, by default it's only allowing loopback/localhost.

See:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html